How to parallelize and minimize the time of a simple code using ParallelTable?
Dear Mathematica users,
I have simplified my real problem, lets say I have 2 matrices, Amat and Bmat, the below code generates a random 2x2 real matrix, B for each of the eth element range from 1 to 10^7 and then the generated Bmat matrix is added into Amat matrix. If I only apply Table function as below:
Amat = ConstantArray[0., {2, 2}];

AbsoluteTiming[
               Table[Bmat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];

                     Amat[[All, All]] = Amat[[All, All]] + Bmat[[All, All]];, {e, 1, 10^7}

                    ]
              ]

The time it takes is 63.6336 [s]. However, if I try to parallelize the code using ParallelTable as below:
Amat = ConstantArray[0., {2, 2}];

AbsoluteTiming[
               ParallelTable[Bmat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];

                             Amat[[All, All]] = Amat[[All, All]] + Bmat[[All, All]];, {e, 1, 10^7}

                            ]
              ]

it takes 83.029 [s] which is greater and it seems that ParallelTable does not use the other kernels effectively by watching the kernel's status with process manager.
I think that Amat needs to be used for each eth loop and e+1th loop waits eth loops work in which Amat is filled and this makes the computational time increase.
What do you suggest me, how could I use the Parallelization, here?
I appreciate for your helps.
Best wishes,
Ahmet

You seem to have background in some other programming language, and you are using programming concepts from there, which are not suitable for Mathematica. (1) Drop the [[All, All]]. (2) Drop defining Bmat, just write Amat += RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]. (3) Try to understand what parallelization actually does and in which cases it is useful.

Your task is nicely parallelizable like this:
n = 10^7;
threadCount = 8

AbsoluteTiming[
 Aglobal = ParallelTable[
    Block[{Aloc},
     Aloc = ConstantArray[0., {2, 2}];
     Do[
      Aloc += RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
      , {Quotient[n, threadCount]}];
     Aloc
     ],
    {threadCount}];
 ]

Amat = Total[Aglobal];


thank you for your reply. I would like to ask about the process. When ParallelTable is called, the code inside ParallelTable[ ] is shared  by the subkernels and executed threadCount times. Additionally, each subkernel has a local copy of Aloc. Do I understand correct? We don't need to specify DistributeDefinitions[  ]. Then we will get the resulted Aglobal list and sum Aglobal list values by using Total [Aglobal].  So, when do we need DistributeDefinitions [ ] if ParallelTable automatically makes a copy of the local variables for the subkernels?

DistributeDefinitions used to be necessary more often in earlier versions of Mathematica. In the meantime, the Parallel constructs became a bit cleverer about pulling necessary definitions from the global scope. But I do not mean to say that it is not necessary anymore. It might still be necessary if you attempt to let all threads modify a shared object. But that should be avoided anyways: shared read-access might be okay, but shrared write-access might require Mathematica to sprinkle in some locks---which might make the parallel loop easily slower than the sequential one.

And yes, each thread gets its own local scratch space Aloc. Because it is scoped with a Block (I should probably have used a Module instead, the memory is also automatically freed in each kernel.

Btw., the use of threadCount (or of the word "thread") is a bit misleading. When starting ParallelTable[...,  {threadCount}] for the first time in a session,Mathematica launches a number of so-called KernelObjects; this number depends on your hardware (and on the configuration). A KernelObject may map to a single CPU core or not. threadCount is rather the number of jobs; Mathematica sends these jobs to the KernelObjects.

Thank you Henrik Schumacher. Ok, if I have a compiled function with the form as:  Compile [ {func arguments}, Block [ {local variables initialization}, ParallelTable [  without block ]  ] . Does this scheme also provide a local copy for the subkernels or do I need to provide a second block for ParallelTable's inside that will make the local variables to be copied.

If you have a homogenous set of CPU cores and roughly equally-sized jobs, then you should try to have as many jobs as you have (performance) cores on your machine. If the job size varies or the CPU core capacities vary, then you might be better off, by creating more and smaller jobs, so that distributing them over the present hardware can even out some bumps.

I mean the two options as: Block[ParallelTable[  ] ] or ParallelTable[ Block [ ]  ] does the guarantee of copying the local variables or is it necessary to use Block inside of the ParallelTable for local copies.

ParallelTable is not compilable. Don't use it within Compile. You can call CompiledFunction created by Compile from within a ParallelTable, though. Note also that Compile has a separate parallelization mechanism via the options RuntimeAttributes->{Listable} and Parallelize->True.

In general, you should declare thread-local variables in a Module or Block within ParallelTable.

It may be that your example is too straightforward.  For example,
AbsoluteTiming[A = Total[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^7, 2, 2}], {1}]]

takes 0.2 seconds on my machine, no parallelization needed.

A side note, too long for the comments.
I know that this is clearly meant as a toy problem, but anyways, just to think out of the box, you could get a tremendous speedup by using a normal distribution as approximation of you final result. With sample size n = 10^7 the difference won't be measurable:
n = 10^7;
\[Mu] = N[n Mean[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]];
\[Sigma] = N[Sqrt[n Variance[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]];
Amat = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {2, 2}];

Even better, request the samples in bulk:
m = 4 * 10^8;
Alist = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {m, 2, 2}];

Running this single-threaded, my machine can do 400 million samples of this in roughly the same time as your original code needs.
